# Selenium Edge error : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Microsoft Edge process

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, edgedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Edge("C:\_Dev\PythonWorkspace\msedgedriver.exe")
```

Before I updated the selenium and edge browser, It worked very well.
I used to work with that code. but, after updating the selenium and edge, It didn't work at all.

the error message is like below:

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: Failed to create Microsoft Edge process.
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66B2AAF02+64226]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B23C0C2+765426]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66AFFCC4C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B02AFF2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B0265FA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B066D3A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B05EDD3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B033BEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B032DD6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B034364]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B488809+1319033]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B0AD2A8]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B1895E1+33553]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B181A1F+1871]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B487423+1313939]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B2446F8+20232]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B240D14+5412]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B240E0C+5660]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B234AC1+735217]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB6F6C7034+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB71382651+33]
  File "C:\_Dev\PythonWorkspace\_python_automation\_FA_maker\pdf_down_ver_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Edge("C:\_Dev\PythonWorkspace\msedgedriver.exe")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Microsoft Edge process.
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66B2AAF02+64226]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B23C0C2+765426]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66AFFCC4C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B02AFF2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B0265FA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B066D3A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B05EDD3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B033BEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B032DD6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B034364]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B488809+1319033]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B0AD2A8]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B1895E1+33553]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B181A1F+1871]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B487423+1313939]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B2446F8+20232]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B240D14+5412]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF66B240E0C+5660]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B234AC1+735217]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB6F6C7034+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB71382651+33]
```

I am so curious why it didn't work.
Many people said that it can be related with the msedgedriver's path. But my msedgedriver's path is not the problem. I think there would be another reason. Because, if I activate the *.py included using the selenium and edgedriver with window task scheduler(by using batch file), My *.py file(with selenium and edgedriver) worked very well.

my selenium version is 4.10 and python is 3.10.
my edge browser version is 114.0.1823.79.

please let me know the solution.

updated the selenium and changed the path for msedgedriver.
rebooted the computer.
uninstalled the selenium and reinstalled.
msedgedriver version updated(same version with edge browser).

Comment: Did the rollback fix the issue? Did you start vscode as administrator?